Verifying that $M$ has curvature $-1$ iff $f''=f$ when $g=dr^2+f(r)^2d\theta^2,M=[0,\infty)_r\times S_\theta^1$
I am currently at a difficult position, because I have to check some definitions/examples regarding hyperbolic surfaces, but I have not taken a proper course on Riemannian manifolds or surfaces in the past. One example is given by
$$M=[0,\infty)_r\times S_\theta^1, g=dr^2+f(r)^2d\theta^2, S^1 = \mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$$
and it is stated verbatim that

$M$ has curvature $-1$ if and only if $f'' = f$.

I don't know how to verify this, and all the sources I managed to find regarding Riemannian surfaces and curvature discuss the subject at so high abstraction level that it's really difficult to pinpoint the important piece(s) that would allow me to verify the claim. And for that reason I turn to this site. So, how is curvature computed in these sort of "easy" examples, and why does $M$ have curvature $-1$ iff $f = f''$?

Do you know the definition of curvature? If so, what is it?

@Deane I do know it in the case of a parameterized curvature in Euclidean space, but I didn't find a suitable reference for a Riemannian surface/manifold.

Not the curvature of a curve. The Gauss curvature of the surface. Why are you trying to do this if you haven’t studied Riemannian geometry?

@Deane Because I got myself involved in a research project with a very enthusiastic professor who assured to me that not having much of background in Riemannian geometry is not really an issue since we are working with measure theoretic tools anyway. And now I am starting to realize that the potential references on the subject I have do not give any easy answers, so in order to verify something simple as this I will probably have to spend the next few months reading nothing but Riemannian geometry.

Try this: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kapovich/RFG/cannon.pdf. It is focused on hyperbolic geometry and contains a brief intro to Riemannian geometry.

@Deane Thank you very much!
